# "отнизу доверху" или "от низу до верху"

Tags: наречия, орфография

> Трибуны сплошь **отнизу доверху** чернели густой человече-
> ской толпой. ([Источник](http://studyport.ru/data/gdz/11/roz.pdf))
>
> Трибуны сплошь **от низу до верху** чернели густой человече-
> ской толпой. ([Источник [2.1]](http://www.mygdz.com/otvet/russkij-yazyk-posobie-dly-cbdb.html))

Как правильно. Для каждого варианта есть примеры в интернете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь возможны два варианта: (1)Трибуны сплошь от низу до верху чернели густой человеческой толпой.  (2)Трибуны сплошь снизу доверху чернели густой человеческой толпой.

По этой теме рекомендуется запомнить следующие выражения: от верха до низа, от низа до верха, сверху донизу, снизу доверху, снизу и до самого верха, сверху и до самого низа.

При слитном написании ударение падает на приставку ДО, при раздельном - на основу существительного.

Слитное написание приставки в наречиях обозначает направление, а раздельное написание предлога - предметное значение существительных ВЕРХ, НИЗ (в авторском толковании).